# How to catch logs of external endpoint getting triggerred in cloudwatch aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

Im new to aws and was trying to use Event brigde and api destination for pinging and endpoint. I am successful in creating api destination and api connection
using cloud formation template and also successfully created IAM role and rule for the same, but i want to have the logs in cloudwatch triggering that endpoint after a scheduled expression. (There is no event triggering that endpoint, i want to trigger it after every 5 min)

Below is my cloud formation template

```
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - events.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: '/jobs-role/'
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: eventbridge-api-destinations
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - events:InvokeApiDestination
                Resource: !GetAtt Destination.Arn

  ApiConnection:
    Type: AWS::Events::Connection
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: API_KEY
      Description: Connection to API
      AuthParameters:
        ApiKeyAuthParameters:
          ApiKeyName: authorization
          ApiKeyValue: MyAPIkey
  Destination:
    Type: AWS::Events::ApiDestination
    Properties:
      ConnectionArn: !GetAtt ApiConnection.Arn
      Description: API Destination to send events
      HttpMethod: POST
      InvocationEndpoint: !Ref ApiDestinationInvocationEndpoint
      InvocationRateLimitPerSecond: 10

  RecordsRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Description: !Sub 'Trigger ${RecordsRole} according to the specified schedule'
      State: ENABLED
      ScheduleExpression: "rate(5 minutes)"
      Targets:
        - Id: !Sub '${RecordsRole}'
          Arn: !GetAtt Destination.Arn
          RoleArn: !GetAtt RecordsRole.Arn
          HttpParameters:
            HeaderParameters:
              Content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8



Can anyone tell me what i am lacking?

Below is link to my screenshot of invocations graph in metrics


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zms44.png
```

Comment: Can you check in CloudWatch Metrics "Triggered Rules" and "Invocations". If invocations are there against triggered rules?. You can also plot them on graph to see time as well

Comment: @AsfarIrshad Pls find my link to screenshot of metrics graph https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfQq2.png 

Im not sure how to check the invocations in graph, are they depicted by orange lines?

Can't i see the same invocations in cloudwatch logs?

Comment: If you hover on orange line you will see dots, you can hover on dots then to see if it was rule or invocation, or both of them

Comment: @AsfarIrshad Its just showing me for TriggerredRules. The graph for invocations is empty. 
Can you tell me difference between both? (Sorry if naive question, Im a newbie to this stuff.)

Comment: Triggered rule means rule is triggered at specified interval, invocation means target invocation. So this means its unable to invoke the target due to lack of permissions probably. Can you please verify if you are granting sufficient IAM permissions and your target is reachable (considering if its under some VPC etc)

Comment: @AsfarIrshad  Im getting https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zms44.png now, It seems invocations are being invoked but they are failing.